# How to pass values in ForEach in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to create ForEach loop and need advice:

1. I have "Fetch" Lookup with "Select CustomerName, Country From Customers".
2. It return rows like "Tesla, USA" and "Nissan, Japan". There are total 10 rows.
3. I would like to run ForEach loop for 10 times and use CustomerName and Country value in pipeline.
4. ForEach settings values are current set: @activity('Fetch').output (something wrong here?)
5. I would like to create new Lookup inside ForEach. I would like in Lookup query "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE CustomerName = 'CustomerName' and Country = 'CountryName'"

[image]

Error of ForEach:

```
 The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'.
```

Comment: Can you share the JSON definition of your pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Items** property of the `For Each` activity should look something like this:

```
@activity('Fetch').output.value
```

You can then reference columns from your `Lookup` within the `For Each` activity using the `item()` syntax, eg `@item().CustomerName`.  Remember, expressions in Azure Data Factory (ADF) start with the `@` symbol but you don't have to repeat it in the string.

[image]

Comment: I modiefied ForEach Expression as "@activity('Fetch').output.value". Tried Sequential disabled and enabled.
Error is given: The expression 'length(activity('Fetch').output.value)' cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist, available properties are 'firstRow, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, billingReference, durationInQueue'.

Comment: Disable the first row property in lookup activity